# How to set up google api project for an app which needs either of 2 scopes?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

We build a ad-network for bloggers (instagram, youtube etc). We want to use google api for 2 use cases:

1. Register user with oauth which requires

   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

both non-sensitive scopes (but still requires app verification)

2. If user wants to add his youtube account into our system, we need youtube data v3 and youtube analytics. Which must be sensitive.

Please advise, how to better set it all up: create 2 different apps (one for sign up, another for youtube) or make one app and request scopes depending on scenario?

Comment: Think about it for a minute. Are you creating two applications or one.  You are creating one application and this application needs specific permissions.    Create a single app.

Comment: So I create one app with 4 scopes. When user registers I only request for profile, later I ask for youtube (if needed). Correct?

Comment: Yes you can request additional permissions at a later date. Your still going to have to verify the app with the YouTube api scope